# Setting up a Qt6 project in CLion with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mingw, clion

I am trying to make a Qt6 application, however I do not like qtcreator so much so I would like to work in CLion. I have been trying to configure my project with CMake but I am kind of new to all that and I am stuck even though I have followed this "tutorial" on the jetbrains website: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#configure-cmakelists

Here is my CMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(VidShare)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH  "C:/Qt/6.1.1/mingw81_64/lib/cmake/")

find_package(Qt6Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_executable(VidShare main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(VidShare Qt6::Widgets)
```

here is my project structure:

```
Vidshare
  \--cmake-build-debug   # This was generated by CLion itself
  \--src                 # Currently empty
  CMakeList.txt
  main.cpp
```

When I click on build I get this message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6Widgets" that is
  compatible with requested version "".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    C:/Qt/6.1.1/mingw81_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Widgets/Qt6WidgetsConfig.cmake, version: 6.1.1 (64bit)
```

Like I said I'm new to cmake so this might be some stupid mistakes but I have been at it for too long and my research did not really bring me anywhere. I am using minGW on windows 10 but I doubt this is the issue at the moment. I also thought that maybe I had to put the Qt libraries in my project or something but I don't know which ones or where to put them but my Qt installation folder is in `C:\Qt\` if that is helpful.

Basically what I want is to setup my environment to be able to work with qt6 in CLion..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I realized I was not using the good version of MinGW (hence the error message). I downloaded the 64bit version of MinGW and tried with that compiler itself and built the project correctly. Moreover I had an issue where it would compile fine but not run and return an error code. I had to put the Qt binaries in my system path variable (`C:\Qt\6.1.1\mingw81_64\bin`) and I can display a window properly with this test code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel label("Hi babygurl!", nullptr);
    label.resize(200, 100);
    label.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with my 2022.3.2 and it seems that the problem is that CMake wants to get a Qt config (with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`) that matches your current toolchain (which is specified in *Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake*). This errors appears whenever you are trying to use a MSVC toolchain on a MinGW Qt instance or vice versa ("incompatiable").
Below is what I set as `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.4.2/msvc2019_64")
```

Comment: It is better to expand such variables instead of overriding. `set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "C:/Qt/6.4.2/msvc2019_64")`

Comment: A better solution can be providing `Qt6_DIR` variable which is used by `find_package(Qt6)` command. It is possible to do so while calling CMake configure. `cmake -D Qt6_DIR="C:/Qt/6.4.2/msvc2019_64" ..`